# How do I continually rename a variable in php?

Tags: php, html

I apologize in advanced because I believe that my question may be kind of confusing.

I have three different PHP files. The first one asks you how many different products you want (1-20) in which the variable is called `$quantity`. Once a number is selected from a drop down box, you are taken to the next PHP page that automatically generates a table with `$quantity` number of rows and in each row there is a dropdown box that is being populated from a database. There is also another column with empty textboxes for the quantity.

Here is the code for that:

```
<?php
            $quantity = "";
            $i = 1;
            if (isset($_POST['quantity'])) {
                $quantity= $_POST['quantity'];
                $var = "";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
                        $var = $var . "<option>" . $row['product_name'] . "</option>";
                    }
                echo "<left><table border='1' width='1%'><tr><td><center>Product</td><td>Quantity</center></td></tr>";
                while ($i <= $quantity){
                echo "<tr><td><select name='product[]' size='1'>";
                echo $var;
                echo "</select></td><td><input name='quant[]'  size='5' /></td></tr>";
                $i++;
                }
                echo "</table></left>";
            }
        ?>
```

Once each product and its desired quantity is entered, the user clicks submit and they are taken to the final PHP page. This PHP page is supposed to be a confirmation page with all of the customer information and their selected products and quantities. HOWEVER, my code is only printing out the LAST product and quantity in the table from the second PHP page. For example if the table is:

```
Product Quantity
Bed     1
Chair   2
Couch   3
```

My confirmation page prints out a one row table with ONLY the information for `Couch` instead of multiple rows with ALL three of those products. Here is my code for the last PHP page:

```
<body>
    <?php
        $curTime= "";
        $customerbox= "";
        $region= "";
        $products = $_POST['product']; //I changed this (edit 2)
        $quants  = $_POST['quant']; //I changed this (edit 2)

        if (isset($_POST['curTime'])) $curTime= $_POST['curTime'];
        if (isset($_POST['customerbox']))$customerbox= $_POST['customerbox'];
        if (isset($_POST['region']))$region= $_POST['region'];
        if (isset($_POST['product']))$product= $_POST['product'];
        if (isset($_POST['quant']))$quant= $_POST['quant'];

        $error= false;
        $done=false;

        if ((isset($curTime) && empty($curTime))) {
            print "Please enter the date.<br/>";
            $error = true;
        }
        if (!isset($_POST['customerbox'])) {
            print "Please select your customer.<br/>";
            $error = true;
        }
        if (!isset($_POST['region'])){
            print "Please select your region.<br/>";
            $error = true;
        }
        if (!isset($_POST['product'])){
            print "Please select your product.<br/>";
            $error = true;
        }
        if ((isset($quant) && empty($quant))){
            print "Please enter the quantity.<br/>";
            $error = true;
        }
        else{
            $error = true;
            $done = true;
        }
        for ($i =0; $i < count($products); $i++){
            echo $products[$i]; //I changed this
            echo $quants[$i]; //I changed this
        }

    ?>

    <br>
    <table style= border-collapse:collapse width="1%"border="2" align="center" <?php if (!$done){ echo "hidden";}?>
        <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>Region</th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>

        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><center><?php print $curTime?></td></center>
        <td><center><?php print $customerbox?></td></center>
        <td><center><?php print $region?></td></center>
        <td><center><?php print $product?></td></center>
        <td><center><?php print $quant?></td><center>

        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

I believe this problem is occurring because when I am creating the table with `$quantity` rows, it's continuously naming each dropdown box `$product` so it's taking the very last value as `$product` and printing that.

Is there anyway to print out all of the products with their respective quantities?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

For your product and quant dropdown boxes you should use `name="product[]"` and `name="quant[]"`.

This will send an array instead of one value as `$_POST` variable, and you can then loop over this array by using

```
$products = $_POST[product];
$quants  = $_POST[quant];
for ($i =0; $i < count($products); $i++){
     echo $products[$i]; //echo one product
     echo $quants[$i]; //echo one quantity
     //etc..
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! quant is actually a textbox. does that make a difference?

Comment: No that doesnt matter, it counts for all input elements.

Comment: Fixed error. Now only printing first character of 'product' and 'quant'.. Example 'couch 3' prints out 'c3'